# GoDaddy External VPS Receive Email Fail

Tags: godaddy, vps, webmin

I have goDaddy Domain with this dns record

```
a   @   107.150.xx.xx   600 seconds     Edit
cname   email   email.secureserver.net  1 Hour  Edit
cname   ftp     @   1 Hour  Edit
cname   www     @   1 Hour  Edit
mx  @   mailstore1.secureserver.net (Priority: 10)  1 Hour  Edit
mx  @   smtp.secureserver.net (Priority: 1)     1 Hour  Edit
ns  @   ns21.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
ns  @   ns22.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour
```

as you can see the domain is pointing to a vps with postfix installed
(this vps is for web server and email server). I've setup the postfix
(via webmin) and successfully sending email, but when i tried to send
email from hotmail to my server, it doesn't receiving, and no error in /var/log/maillog

i'm suspecting there's something in the dns that i need to configure

can somebody pin point it for me? thanks

Comment: Can u mark my correct answer? If it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The 'A' record means nothing as far as mail is concerned.

The 'MX' record takes care of directing emails.

Your emails from your hotmail account are being sent to 'mailstore1.secureserver.net'.

If your email addresses are not setup within GoDaddy's system then they are likely just getting dropped.

To solve your issue change your 'MX' record to match the server where your email server is. (Using your provided info this would be the IP you have listed in the A record)